# In This code why does the value of firstvalue does came out as 20

Tags: c++

In this code why does the value of firstvalue does not came as 20. At last i have changed the value of pointer p1 to 20. So p1 should assign the value of firstvalue address to 20.

```
// more pointers
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
int * p1, * p2;
p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
*p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
*p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed by p1
p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
*p1 = 20;          // value pointed by p1 = 20

cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your question title, you ask why the value of firstvalue comes out as 20. In your question body, you ask why the value of firstvalue does *not* come out as 20. It looks like a mistake in your question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the final schema:

```
 +--+      +---+
 |p1|      | p2|
 +--+      +---+
    |        |  
    --       |
      \      v 
       +-----------+
       |secondValue|
       +-----------+
            20
```

`secondValue` is 20 since you're changing the value presented in `p1`, which points to `secondValue`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `p1 = p2` reassigns `p1` to point to `secondvalue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When u assign`p1=p2` you assign the address pointed by p2 to p1. Now both p1 and p2 point to secondValue. This does not change firstValue.